# Python ImportError: No module named main in Google app engine project

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have the following app.yaml file

```
application: gtryapp
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes

handlers:

- url: /images/(.*\.(gif|png|jpg))
  static_files: static/img/\1
  upload: static/img/(.*\.(gif|png|jpg))

- url: /css/(.*\.css)
  mime_type: text/css
  static_files: static/css/\1
  upload: static/css/(.*\.css)

- url: /js/(.*\.js)
  mime_type: text/javascript
  static_files: static/js/\1
  upload: static/js/(.*\.js)

- url: /(.*\.html)
  mime_type: text/html
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/(.*\.html)

- url: .*
  script: main.app


libraries:

- name: webapp2
  version: "2.5.2"
```

And the file app.py:

```
import webapp2

class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
def get(self):
    if self.request.url.endswith('/'):
        path = '%sindex.html'%self.request.url
    else:
        path = '%s/index.html'%self.request.url

    self.redirect(path)


    application = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/.*', MainPage)],
                                     debug=True)
```

The files that I should deploy are just html files or js or images, I get the following error after compiling the app:

raise ImportError('%s has no attribute %s' % (handler, name))
ImportError:  has no attribute app

---

Solved: I had to call "app" not "application" !

```
    app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/.*', MainPage)],
                                     debug=True)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You've called the file index.py, not main.py. Either rename it, or use `index.app` in the yaml.

Comment: you are right man thank you sorry for the noobness ... please i have another error in _LoadHandler
    raise ImportError('%s has no attribute %s' % (handler, name))
ImportError: <module 'main' from '/Users/francescotangari/gtryapp/main.py'> has no attribute app

Comment: You need to get rid of the `if __name__ = "__main__"` stuff, as well as the `def main()` line, and just put the things inside that function at the module level.

Comment: please can you explain me what do you mean with "put the things inside that function at the module level" ?

Comment: @frank it looks like you skipped the tutorial.. :) https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/ make sure you went through it at least once till the end..

Comment: @Lipis i need this https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/staticfiles right ?

Comment: @Lipis i read it right now but i still don't get what menas put the things inside that function at the module level

Comment: @frank you need to do start and finish this tutorial as is.. as a new project before trying to implement them on your current one..

Comment: ok i wrote this : import webapp2

class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        if self.request.url.endswith('/'):
            path = '%sindex.html'%self.request.url
        else:
            path = '%s/index.html'%self.request.url

        self.redirect(path)


application = webapp.WSGIApplication([('/.*', IndexHandler)],
                                         debug=True) but still not works

Comment: @Lipis i still have the problem on  ImportError: has no attribute app

Answer (score 2):

The issue you are having is that your `app.yaml` file doesn't properly describe your code. Here is the offending bit:

```
- url: .*
  script: main.app
```

This says that all URLs that were not matched by some previous entry should be handled by the `app` object of the `main` module, which should be a WSGI application object (see the WSGI standard).

This doesn't work because your code is set up differently. Your primary module is in `index.py` (the `index` module) and its interface with the server is via the CGI standard (though WSGI is used internally).

So, you need to change something. It could either be the `app.yaml` description of the app, or it could be the organization of your code.

Making your code work as a CGI-style program is easy. Just change `app.yaml` to point to `index.py` as the script. The `.py` part in this case is the file extension, and the file will be run as a script.

If instead you want to go with the newer, WSGI-compatible style (which is probably the best option), [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig#Script_Handlers) suggests the following format:

```
import webapp2

class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'
        self.response.out.write('Hello, webapp World!')

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainPage)])
```

Your code is almost like this already. To make it work, get rid of your `main` function and `if __name__ == "__main__"` boilerplate. Replace it with:

```
app = webapp.WSGIApplication([('/.*', IndexHandler)],
                              debug=False)
```

This creates an `app` object at the top level of your module. Now, either rename your `index.py` file to `main.py`, or change `app.yaml` to point to `index.app`. The `.app` part of this is different this time. Rather than a file extension, it represents Python member access (in this case, accessing a global variable in a module).

Comment: i stil get  ImportError: has no attribute app