# Django gives "502 Bad Gateway" error on Google App Engine

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, google-app-engine

I'm trying to deploy a Django application on Google App Engine in the Standard Python3.8 environment. I followed all the steps in [this document](https://cloud.google.com/python/django/appengine). App runs fine on my local with google cloud database. However I receive `502 Bad Gateway` error visiting Web Url. I found a lot of different questions but technology is changing a lot, and none of them helped so far. Lastly, I came across with [this solution](https://medium.com/@umeshsaruk/upload-to-google-cloud-storage-using-django-storages-72ddec2f0d05) today, but it says create a `gcloud.py` file that I never seen in google documents that's why I haven't applied that solution but decided to ask you.

I get this error when visiting page

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
_find_and_load (<frozen importlib._bootstrap>)
```

And this is the stack trace from the error:

```
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 973, in _find_and_load_unlocked: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'main'
at _find_and_load (<frozen importlib._bootstrap>:991)
at _gcd_import (<frozen importlib._bootstrap>:1014)
at import_module (/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py:127)
at import_app (/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py:358)
at load_wsgiapp (/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py:39)
at load (/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py:49)
at wsgi (/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py:67)
at load_wsgi (/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py:144)
at init_process (/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py:119)
at init_process (/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/gthread.py:92)
at spawn_worker (/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py:583)
```

my_site/wsgi.py

```
import os
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "my_site.settings")
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

This is my app.yaml

```
runtime: python38 
handlers:
# This configures Google App Engine to serve the files in the app's
# static directory.
- url: /static
 static_dir: static/
# This handler routes all requests not caught above to the main app. 
# It is required when static routes are defined, but can be omitted 
# (along with the entire handlers section) when there are no static 
# files defined.
- url: /.*
 script: auto
```

This is the settings.py. I tried with the commented lines but it still gives same error.

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = 'static'

# STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '/static/')
# STATICFILES_DIRS = (
#     os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
# )
# MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
# MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "media")

# STATICFILES_FINDERS = [
#    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
#    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
# ]
```

appengine_config.py

```
from google.appengine.ext import vendor
vendor.add('lib')
```

And I have these 2 libraries in my lib folder. I moved them manually from env folder.

```
django
MySQLdb
```

Comment: It seems that you're having a problem with your entry point, could you check if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52416588/python-3-django-on-app-engine-standard-app-fails-to-start) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15722882/python-importerror-no-module-named-main-in-google-app-engine-project) helps?

Comment: I actually tried the first link and it didn't work but I will keep trying in different versions of the first links. Btw even after a line change in the app.yaml,  have to deploy like usual, or is there another way to deploy only changes.

Comment: It's not possible to upload only the changes, you have to upload and deploy everything when you make changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The application is complaining about not finding the `main` module, the document that you [mentioned](https://medium.com/@umeshsaruk/upload-to-google-cloud-storage-using-django-storages-72ddec2f0d05) aboards a different problem than yours, you're not reaching the point of using the storage library.

Regarding your specific problem. As mentioned in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/runtime#application_startup):

> The runtime starts your app by running the command you specify in the
> entrypoint field in your app.yaml file.

In this case your `app.yaml` isn't specifying an entrypoint, when this happens you have to make sure that you fulfill the next requirements:

> If your app meets the following requirements, App Engine will start
> your app with the gunicorn web server if you don't specify the
> entrypoint field:
>
> The root of your app directory contains a main.py file with a
> WSGI-compatible object called app.
>
> Your app does not contain Pipfile or Pipfile.lock files.

In this case your application is lacking the `main.py` file which is the error App Engine is complaining about. There are multiple ways to avoid this error (like specifying an [entrypoint](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/runtime#entrypoint_best_practices)). What I suggest in this case is to create a file named `main.py` on your **root** folder of your app and include the next:

```
from mysite.wsgi import application
app = application
```

An example containing the structure required to run a Django app can be found [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/tree/master/appengine/standard_python3/django)

Comment: Thanks a lot @Emmanuel, it helped. Btw I accidentally created a public repository on GitHub which held all my passwords, and it caused my google engine app compromised. I need to find a way to load secret keys and passwords in a separated file.

Comment: I recommend you to use a [gitifnore](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) file so you avoid to upload those files into github